# Remove FolderName.exe virus from pen drive

Tags: anti-virus

When I shift a folder into my pen drive, the folder is hidden and the same(folder).exe is created against the folder. how to solve it. I have tried with formatting the pen drive. No result. Please help me..

Thank you

Ashish

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Answer (score 1):

try this
http://4paisa.blogspot.com/2008/05/clean-new-folderexe-regsvrexe-virus.html

You may have to change the bat file according to the number of drives you have.

But, I think this question should be moved to ServerFault

Comment: I think SuperUser would be more approriate than ServerFault.

Answer (score 1):

please use this simple Code to delete the exe files created according to your folder names. and modify the pendrive drive name inside the code, for example I mentioned as f:

save the code as super.exe and run it in command prompt as **Scriptlocation**:\cscript.exe super.exe

```
Option Explicit

Const DeleteReadOnly = True 
Dim oFSO, oDrive, sFileName

Set oFSO   = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
sFileName  = ".exe"

For Each oDrive In oFSO.Drives 
  If oDrive.DriveType = 2 Then Recurse oFSO.GetFolder("F:\")
Next 

Sub Recurse(oFolder)
  Dim oSubFolder, oFile
wscript.echo oFolder.name
  If IsAccessible(oFolder) Then
    For Each oSubFolder In oFolder.SubFolders
     Recurse oSubFolder
    Next 

    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        sFileName = oFolder.name & ".exe"
      If oFile.Name = sFileName Then
        oFile.Delete ' or whatever
      End If
    Next 
  End If
End Sub

Function IsAccessible(oFolder)
  On Error Resume Next
  IsAccessible = oFolder.SubFolders.Count >= 0
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This is basic property of many Viruses.

Your computer itself is infected with the virus and this activity is done by that that virus process running in your computer.

Clean your computer first using followings:
1) stop virus process using 'Rkill'
2) use tools like 'Microsoft security scanner'
3) install MalwareBytes, update, Do a Full scan
4) install a antivirus (Microsoft security essentials or Avast free)

now connect your Pendrive, scan it also (as infected)

[For details see here](http://tech-soln.blogspot.co.at/2012/11/how-to-clean-your-computer-from-virus.html).